"System.Net.WebException" saat Mengambil Daftar Bucket?
can you help me this my EROR [I] [2024-06-15 08:43:38] Error occurred during Getting buckets list..   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
I hope it can run and can connect to s3browsers`your text
